# C ++ , getting error in vector , after reading text file line by line

Tags: c++, file-io, visual-studio-2015

Here's what I want to do,

While reading the text file line by line and splitting each line, I want to it to check if the ID (first one) is equal to the ID I want. If it equals then put the rest of the line into a vector except the ID.

Text file(example):

```
11111 Mark 100 40 30
11112 Helen 90 50 20
11113 John 20 20 80
11114 Paul 50 40 10
11115 Hank 10 10 20
```

Here is my code so far, but for some reason I am getting a "vector subscript out of range" error.

```
#include...

using namespace std;



vector <string> Grades;

void getgrades(string x) {
    string gtemp;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("Test.txt");
    while (getline(myfile, gtemp)) {
       stringstream ss(gtemp);
       string ToBe;
       while (getline(ss, ToBe, ' ')) {
          Grades.push_back(ToBe);
        }
        if (Grades[0] != x) {
          Grades.clear();
        }
        else {
         Grades.erase(Grades.begin());
        }
  }
}


int main() {
    string x;
    cout << "Enter the ID: ";
    cin >> x;
    getgrades(x);
    cout << "Name:" << Grades[0] << endl;
    cout << "Grades: " << Grades[1] << " " << Grades[2] << " "<< Grades[3] <<endl;



  return 0;
}
```

p.s: I am using VS2015.

Comment: Are you sure that your vector contains 4 elements? Did you try printing `Grades.size ()`?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have found the correct line, you don't exit the outer while.

So the outer while loop continues and as the next line will not match the ID,  your vector will get cleared. So you will necessarily be out of boudns when you try to access any elements.

To correct just complete your code as follows:

```
 ...
 else {
     Grades.erase(Grades.begin());
     break; //<============ exit the outer while
    }
```

*One suggestion though:  you can never be sure that the user enters a valid ID. You should in any case verify how many elements you have in the vector before trying to access them (as s.o. suggested in the comments).*

Comment: More like there should be a different `Grades` vector for each person, it gets modified (clearing, erasing), then pushed to the main vector.

Comment: @LogicStuff indeed, if OP intends to load everything in memory, rather than performing one operation at a time on the file. Then a`map<string, vector<string>>` could make sense to access to the grades by ID.

Comment: Thank you for the correction. I just can't believe how I missed that small detail...

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong.

F.e. you entered ID = 11111, then after first *'while (getline(myfile, gtemp))'* loop you will have this in your 'Grades' vector:

Grades[0] = Mark

Grades[1] = 100

Grades[2] = 40

Grades[3] = 30

after this the next *'while (getline(myfile, gtemp))'* will clear your Grades vector, because Grades[0] = Mark, and it's not equal to x anymore

Answer (score 0):

You keep reading after finding the id, and clear the vector on the next id, leaving it empty.

You can break immediately when you've found `x` and gathered its grades.

You also don't need to collect grades for everyone and clear them, you can skip the lines you're not interested in (and globals are bad, mmkay?):

```
vector<string> getgrades(string x) {
    vector<string> grades;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile("Test.txt");
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string id;
        if (ss >> id && id == x)
        {
            string grade;
            while (ss >> grade) {
                grades.push_back(grade);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return grades;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should return after erase, otherwise you will get garbage value.